# JQuery Post to NodeJS return MySQL value gives undefined?

Tags: jquery, mysql, node.js

So I'm trying to make a basic query to my database and pull back one value with JQuery.

JQuery Code:

```
function getTokens(user, cb) {     
    $.post("/getTokens", {username: user}, function(data) {
        return cb(data);
    });
}
```

Node:

```
app.post('/getTokens', function(req, res) {
    connection.query('select tokens from users where username = "' + req.body.username + '"', function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err)
            console.error(err)
        else {
            res.send(rows[0].tokens.toString());
        }
    });
});
```

I want to store the returned value in a string. In the callback function, if I console.log or alert the 'tokens' parameter it correctly shows it, however if I just return it like I have below, 'tokens' is undefined when I apply it to the #username_field. Like so:

```
totalTokens = getTokens(username, function(tokens){
    // console.log(tokens); why does this work, but the line below doesn't? 
    return tokens;
});

$('#username_field').text('Tokens: ' + tokens);
```

If anyone can help me get the returned value 'tokens' onto my #username_field that would be awesome. Any suggestions would be helpful, it's driving me nuts that it keeps returning undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The node part looks fine.

Do this instead for your front end. Get rid of the return and the variable, you don't need that:

```
getTokens(username, function(tokens){
$('#username_field').text('Tokens: ' + tokens);
});
```

Fyi, Your code is using variables incorrectly. The jquery portion would use totalTokens, not tokens.